# Continuous versus Discrete to describe a set of integers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the proper way to describe a set of integers that is infinite versus a set that contains a limited number of integers? I've seen a `variable` described as continuous or discrete and I want to know if it's proper to say $Z$ contains a continuous set of integers, whereas $Z_9$ contains a discrete set of integers?

Comment: You would say "Let $A$ be a finite set of integers."  If you want to specify the integers you sould say "Let $A = \{2, 4, 9\}$" or "Let $A = \{1,2, ..., 10\}$."  For infinite you would say "Let $A$ be an infinite set of integers" or "Let $A = \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$" or "Let $A= \{n : n = z^2 \: \mbox{ for some $z \in \mathbb{N}$}\}$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One says "a finite set of integers" and "an infinite set of integers" or (but this sounds odd) "non finite set of integers".

"Discrete" and "continuous" describe something else.

Comment: For context, would it matter if one were describing the difference in the number of  integers in $Z$ versus the result of a Discrete Log $Z_p$ or would you still use the terms infinite versus finite?

Comment: Finite and infinite refer to how many elements a set has, not how big it is. Thus, $\{\pm\infty\}$ is a finite set of infinities, and $\mathbb Z$ is an infinite set of finite numbers, and so on.

Comment: First, thanks for your patience. Second, I'm trying to wrap my brain around, "Finite and infinite refer to how many elements a set has, not how big it is." with the examples you provide. If I wanted to distinguish the integers in $ℤ$ versus the integers in $Z_p$, what terms would you use?

Comment: I meant to write, "not how big the elements are_".  Sorry.   I'm not sure I understand your "if I wanted to distinguish".  If I were writing informally, I'd use"an integer" as opposed to "a field element" or "a residue".  In a formal context, I'd say "an element of $\mathbb Z$" or "an element of $\mathbb Z_p$.